# enable the disabled Ethernet network adapter using WMI, VC++

Tags: c++, adapter, ethernet

I want to enable the Ethernet network adapter if it is disabled only. But If I can't do that it is acceptable to enable all network adapters. 
I saw a lot of materials and links.
I know that we can do it by Using IP Helper, Device Installation API, Shell Network Interfaces, or WMI.
I tried an example to do that by the IP Helper and SetIfEntry() and GetIfEntry() functions. it didn't do any changes. In addition for that I am afraid that it doesn't work if the user doesn't have administrative rights.
I tried after that to do that by WMI, but I may have some missing data about that. I can't know how to call the Enable() method in Win32_NetworkAdapter class, As I don't know what I need to write firstly before creating an object

I need that in C++ code as it is a small part inside fn in my project.

So, Can any one help me with small code which enable the ethernet network 
As I want if I disables it manually from control panel the code enables it

Note: I don't want any way to do that if it may need to reboot the machine and I want it to be acceptable for all windows

the tag code is one I tried to use enable method after it gets the Mac address

WMI Tasks: Networking
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394595(v=vs.85).aspx

Win32_NetworkAdapter class
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394216(v=vs.85).aspx

Thanks in advance